# SPARQL - Restricting Result Resource to Certain Namespace(s)

Tags: sparql

Is there a standard way of restricting the results of a SPARQL query to belong to a specific namespace.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Short answer - no there is no standard direct way to do this

Long answer - However yes you can do a limited form of this with the string functions and a `FILTER` clause.  What function you use depends on what version of SPARQL your engine supports.

### SPARQL 1.1 Solution

Almost all implementations will these days support [SPARQL 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) and you can use the [`STRSTARTS()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts) function like so:

```
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?var), "http://example.org/ns#"))
```

This is my preferred approach and should be relatively efficient because it is simple string matching.

### SPARQL 1.0 Solution

If you are stuck using an implementation that only supports [SPARQL 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) you can still do this like so but it uses regular expressions via the [`REGEX()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#funcex-regex) function so will likely be slower:

```
FILTER(REGEX(STR(?var), "^http://example\\.org/ns#"))
```

#### Regular Expressions and Meta-Characters

Note that for the regular expression we have to escape the meta-character `.` as otherwise it could match any character e.g. `http://exampleXorg/ns#foo` would be considered a valid match.

As `\` is the escape character for both regular expressions and SPARQL strings it has to be double escaped here in order to get the regular expression to have just `\.` in it and treat `.` as a literal character.

### Recommendation

If you can use SPARQL 1.1 then do so because using the simpler string functions will be more performant and avoids the need to worry about escaping any meta-characters that you have when using `REGEX`