# SPARQL prefix wildcard

Tags: sparql

I'm attempting to write a SPARQL query which would allow me to find all nodes which are reachable from a given node. At the moment every edge has the prefix http://www.foo.com/edge# and there are 3 possible edges (uses, extends, implements). While I can get the correct result from "?start (edge:uses | edge:implements | edge:extends)* ?reached " I would like to reduce that down to one statement, some kind of wildcard after edge:, so that if I add more edge types then I wouldn't need to extend the query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see this [SPARQL - Restricting Result Resource to Certain Namespace(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597981/sparql-restricting-result-resource-to-certain-namespaces)

If you know it's always going to be in the same namespace, you could have something looking like:

```
?start ?edge ?reached
FILTER(REGEX(STR(?var), "^http://www.foo.com/edge#"))
```

Comment: The [`strstarts()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts) function might be faster.