# SPARQL Query to Identify Predicates from One of Many Graphs

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I have created an ontology by grouping together many ontologies.

I want to use SPARQL to identify all middle terms (relationships) from one ontology from the group ontology.

The following approach only produces a `pyparsing error`.

```
g = rdflib.Graph()
result = g.parse("without-bfo.owl")

qres = g.query(
 """ PREFIX sudo: <http://purl.url/sudo/ontology#>
     SELECT ?v
    WHERE {
      ?s sudo:?v ?o.
   }""")
```

If I remove the `sudo:` prefix, this query returns all triples.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the relation starts with your namespace with `CONTAINS`

```
SELECT ?v
WHERE {
  ?s ?v ?o.
  FILTER CONTAINS(?v, "http://purl.url/sudo/ontology#")
}
```

You can also try `STRSTARTS`

see [w3 documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains)

Comment: This returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

@Arcturus was close.

The following worked for me. One has to declare `?v` as a string using `STR`. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597981/sparql-restricting-result-resource-to-certain-namespaces#9605812) suggested the syntax.

```
qres = g.query(
""" SELECT DISTINCT ?v
    WHERE {
      ?s ?v ?o . 
      FILTER CONTAINS(STR(?v), "sudo")
   }""")
```

for row in qres:
    print row